# Best way to handle concurrency with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, concurrency, entity-framework-4.1

I am using entity framework 4.1.What is the best way to handle concurrency with entity framework. Is there inbuilt functionality to handle it in entity framework?
Can I do without adding extra column to the tables to keep row version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

You can do it without a rowversion column but that often requires storing a lot of state, which can adversely affect performance.

Answer (score 26):

You can set up a column in your tables named RowVersion and tell Entity Framework that you want this column to be included in the where clauses of all UPDATE and DELETE statements. You then ensure that you increment this field for all changed entities. I've done it like this:

```
//make all entities that need concurrency implement this and have RowVersion field in database
public interface IConcurrencyEnabled
{
    int RowVersion { get; set; }
}
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach(var dbEntityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {
            IConcurrencyEnabled entity = dbEntityEntry.Entity as IConcurrencyEnabled;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.RowVersion = entity.RowVersion + 1;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //do all your custom model definition but have the following also:
        modelBuilder.Entity<myEntity>().Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read this question. it has a different idea thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412690/entity-framework-objectcontext-concurrency

Comment: Can't I do it without a row version column?

Comment: I guess you could set more than one property with `IsConcurrencyToken()` and EF will add these columns in the where clause of your update and delete statements. I have not tested this though.

Comment: Yes, it works with multiple properties as concurrency tokens, I just had a situation where I tested it. All concurrency properties are included in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks, as I found we need a small change to make sure that row version of new records are set to 1:                          if(dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
                        entity.RowVersion = 1;
                    else if(dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                        entity.RowVersion = entity.RowVersion + 1;