# Entity Framework Concurrency control using "Timestamp" value check

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, ef-code-first

For concurrency control i Write "VersionCheck" function in my Context class,I need to dynamically load Context object and check if version is the same as the current context object RowVersion. now i use switch statement.  (code below)
and also, Is there more convenient way for version control?

p.s. RowVersion is TimeStamp type in Database.

```
  public class SchoolContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public bool VersionCheck(string objName)
    {
        var dbc = new SchoolContext();
        byte[] bt1 = null;
        byte[] bt2 = null;

        switch (objName)
        {
            case "Person":
                dbc.Persons.Load();
                bt1 = dbc.Persons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).RowVersion;
                bt2 = this.Persons.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).RowVersion;
                break;
            case "Group":
                dbc.Groups.Load();
                bt1 = dbc.Groups.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).RowVersion;
                bt2 = this.Groups.Local.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1).RowVersion;
                break;
        }

        if (bt1 == null && bt2 == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("One of the Variable is null!");
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bt1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bt1[i] != bt2[i])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Current object changed!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

 }
```

Comment: have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6554939/5984

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why do you have 2 separate db context? Are you using the ConcurrencyCheckAttribute for the timestamp or this is a custom solution? If so then what is your goal (again)?

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. I edited code. there is only SchoolContext.

Comment: You _have_ to use optimistic concurrency as described. It is the only way to do the check _while_ updating. Your approach always leaves room for conflicts between the check and the actual update.

Answer (score 1):

[Optimistic concurrency explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx)

The described approach looks like data corruption waiting to happen.
Unless you are locking the row or table during the time you read and check the rowversion, then it can change after to you have read it to check its value.

Use Optimistic concurrency paradigm properly.

eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/14718991/1347784