# EF: Increase a field by X

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to increase `Quantity` property of `Stock` entity by `X` units say 10. But any effort using EF fails because the appropriate SQL statement (`Quantity = Quantity + 10`) is not generated and instead (`Quantity = 110`) is generated. This is important in concurrent model;

```
var db = new WarehouseContext();
Stock s = db.Stocks.Single(p=>p.Id==1);
Console.WriteLine(s.Quantity); // --> 100
s.Quantity += 10;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This will generates:

```
UPDATE dbo.Stock SET Quantity = 110;
```

But, I want this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Stock SET Quantity = Quantity + 10;
```

Comment: What prevents you from using simple SQL instead?

Comment: You need to execute that SQL yourself, EF and other ORMs can only persist what they have in memory right now, they don't work out any sort of "diff" between what you loaded and what you want to save.

Comment: Is there a point to doing that.  The only difference would be where the calculation is done (host vs database server).

Comment: If you are really intent on avoiding raw SQL (for portability reasons maybe?), then you can also check out [this EF extension](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). Look for the **Batch Update and Delete** section.  Otherwise, depending on your DBMS, you could also look at adding some form of version column to do optimistic concurrency. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554860/best-way-to-handle-concurrency-with-entity-framework) for some ideas.

Comment: If I port the calculation into DB, it certainly scatter business rules over the system and call for more effort to maintain. This is why I don't like SP or trigger. But thanks everybody for elaboration.

Comment: @Hans: You do know that you can also execute raw SQL from EF (and avoid SP or trigger, if that's what you want), right?  From your example, you could: `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.Stock SET Quantity = Quantity + 10")`

Comment: @SamStanojevic: Yes. But I expected EF does this for me without explicitly telling it what to do.